# Why Urysohn's metrization theorem must hold? And what is its motivation?

Tags: general-topology

Urysohn Metrization Theorem: If $(X\tau)$ is second countable $T_3$, then there exists an imbedding $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\omega$.

By using Urysohn's Lemma, there exists a countable family of continuous functions $f_n:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\forall (x\in X \bigwedge U\in \tau), x\in U \Rightarrow \exists n\in \omega (f_n(x)>0 \bigwedge f_n\upharpoonright U^c = 0)$.

Define a function $F(x)(n) = f_n(x)$.

Then this function $F$ is an imbedding from $X$ into $[0,1]^\omega$.

========

It's not obvious to me why this function $F$ is an imbedding. How do i visualize this function? And what is the motivation of this theorem?

Answer (score 1):

> It's not obvious to me why this function $F$ is an imbedding.

Look 2.3.23 in Ryszard Engelking’s “[General Topology](http://webfile.ru/efb452cf7fb36adbe54307b44eb8657f)”.

> How do i visualize this function?

I don’t know how to visualize this embedding.

> And what is the motivation of this theorem?

Motivation is that the space $\mathbb R^\omega$ (or $[0;1]^\omega$) is a universal metrisable space for second countable regular spaces.